# Azure App Registration get Date of consent given for multi tenant app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-app-registration

I have a multi tenant app running and received a request from a "customer" where he claims that he never gave consent to my terms of service and privacy statement. While I claimed that since the beginning the two fields were set in my app registration and required for the use of the app, I did not find any means to prove this, nor any API-Endpoint where I could verify the date the "customer" gave consent to the two links which are configured.

Is there any API (or other possibility) to get the date a customer gave consent to my app registration?

Comment: Consent for your T&Cs isn't the same thing as accepting the Azure AD consent dialog...

Comment: According to GDPR , the user must explicitly agree by any action (like click on acceppt) to the referenced versions of the T&C. By referencing this as done by azure here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-terms-of-service-privacy-statement#user-consent-experience this fulfills the requirement. So I argue in this case it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, you can find consent grant date in audit logs of **customer
> tenant** not app publisher's tenant.

To get the **date** on which customer gave consent, you can run below MS Graph query in customer's tenant:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Consent to application' and result eq 'success' and targetResources/any(c:c/id eq 'spObjID') and initiatedBy/user/id eq 'userId'
```

I registered one Multi-tenant application named **`SriMultiApp`** in one Azure AD directory and got **consent prompt** when user signs in with below request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=<appId>&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=User.Read&response_mode=form_post&prompt=consent&nonce=123456778
```

[image]

Once the user **accepted** the above consent, it will be reflected in **`Permissions`** tab of your Enterprise application like this:

[image]

You can find the **date** on which customer gave consent to app registration by checking **Audit logs** of your application in customer's tenant:

[image]

When I ran below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by signing in with **Global Administrator** account of customer's tenant, I got date in **`activityDateTime`** variable successfully:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Consent to application' and result eq 'success' and targetResources/any(c:c/id eq 'spObjID') and initiatedBy/user/id eq 'userId'
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Note that while this is all true, it's only true *in the customer's tenant*, not in the app publisher's tenant (assuming it's different).

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I agree with you, consent grant date will be found in audit logs of **customer tenant** not app publisher's tenant. Updated the answer with `Note`.

Answer (score 0):

A customer's Entra (formerly known as Azure AD) audit logs would have included a record every time consent was granted for an app: [Microsoft Entra audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs).

In the general case (where you and your customer are from two different organizations, each with your own Entra tenants), you as the app developer/publisher, will not have access to the customer's audit logs, and will not have a record on your side of the consent being granted.

Some considerations about the Entra consent prompt:

1. It's for authorizing an app to access customer-controlled data, at resources (e.g. APIs) secured by Entra ID.
2. There's no guarantee all users who use the app have seen the consent prompt. A sufficiently privileged admin can consent on behalf of all users.
3. There is no guarantee or telemetry about whether the user clicked on the app's terms and privacy links.
4. There is no record of what the URLs or the content behind those URLs were at the time when consent was granted.

In short: if you have requirements to obtain customer consent for something other than API access (e.g. for your terms of service or privacy policy or other agreement), you need to build that into your app.

Note: In the general case of a multi-tenant app, consent *is* needed in order for a user to successfully sign in. If your app kept a record of when the users in that organization first successfully signed in, that's when (those users, at least) granted consent.